# Poner tiempo a beforeSend y Success

Tags: ajax, timeout

se puede poner tiempo al before send, es decir al menos que la carga del beforeSend tarde 1sec, y luego después del success quiero cerrar el modal y tendrá que tener un lapso de tiempo. Probe con el `timeout` pero no hace nada...

```
     $(function(){
          $("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");

              $.ajax({
                  url: "datos.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,


                   beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#mensaje").html("<div class='ui active inline loader myLoader'></div>")
                    },
                   timeout:200000,

                   success: function (resultado){
                     $("#mensaje").html(resultado);

                  }

                });
             });
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `Ajax`, tal y como lo estás haciendo no se le puede poner un tiempo de espera al `beforeSend`. Y teniendo en cuenta de que necesitas el resultado para poder mostrarlo creo que no tienes más opción que la de poner el `timeout` en el `success`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería.

```
$(function(){
          $("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");

              $.ajax({
                  url: "datos.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,


                   beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#mensaje").html("<div class='ui active inline loader myLoader'></div>")
                    },
                   timeout:200000,

                   success: function (resultado){

                     setTimeout(function(){ $("#mensaje").html(resultado); }, 1000);    
                  }

                });
             });
          });
```

Esto hará que cuando obtengas los resultados espere un segundo antes de cambiar el texto de `#mensaje`

Comment: Muchas gracias! de momento me es suficiente así!

Comment: Me alegro, si encuentro alguna otra cosa ya te aviso!